# Viewing Account chatter feed in communities

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter

I am using the connect API to provide a visualforce page with feed items for an Account. Unfortunately, my community user seem to only be able to view his own posts, not ones made by the internal users. I know I am probably missing a setting and my face is ready for palming, but what am I missing here?

Comment: I am not sure what you need, but isn't that way it should work? I mean sharing rules still apply to FeedItems... As I understand you want to skip Sharing(without sharing class)?

Comment: I tried without sharing but that didnt seem to fix it. Looking at this article from SF, https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_post_visibility.htm , it looks like anyone who can view the account should be able to see the feed. I am just wondering if there are special considerations for community users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an internal user posts a feed item to an Account (or any other type of record), there's an option to control the visibility of the feed item. The options are to make it visible to internal users only, or to make it visible to all users who have access to it. The default is to make it visible to internal users only, so that community users don't see the post. That's probably what you're running into. Here's where the option is in the Salesforce UI:

[image: Record post visbility]

If you log in as an internal user, you can get the details of the feed item via the API and then inspect the "visibility" property of the [ConnectApi.FeedItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_Feed_Item.htm) to see if the theory's correct.

When you post a feed item via the API, you can set the visibility property in the [ConnectApi.FeedItemInput](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_input_feedItem.htm) class to achieve the same thing that the visibility drop-down in the UI does.